# ModelMapper with STRICT Matching Strategy

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

I have the following **Entity Classes:**

```
class Provider{
    private String providerId;
    private String identificationNumber;
    private Account account;

  // Setters, Getters and toString
}

class Account {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

   // Setters, Getters and toString
}
```

**DTO:**

```
class ProviderDTO{
    private String providerId;
    private String identificationNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String accountLastname;

   //Setters, Getters and toString
 }
```

If I try to map my **DTO** to the **Provider** entity using (`MatchingStrategies.STRICT`):

```
Provider provider = modelMapper.map(providerDTO,Provider.class);
```

`provider.getAccount().getName()` is **null** and
`provider.getAccount().getName()` is **null**

But if I using a (`MatchingStrategies.STANDARD`):
Works perfectly....

`provider.getAccount().getName()` is **not null** and
`provider.getAccount().getName()` is **not null**

My question is: how should I name the properties of my DTO so that modelmapper works in STRICT mode?

I would like to receive an explanation of how strict mode works, because I did not find examples, even on the official modelmapper website. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The STRICT matching strategy is not supporting this kind of mapping (hierarchical -> flat or flat -> hierarchical).

Please refer the docs here: [matching strategy](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies) and the unit test for STRICT matching strategy: [StrictMatchingStrategyTest](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/modelmapper/convention/StrictMatchingStrategyTest.java#L25)